# How do I make a command block not have the typical [@] infront of a /say msg in MCPE?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

If I write `/say @p is cool` into a command block, what pops up in the chat is:

`[@]LolybeeHD is cool`

How can I change the @ to something else (like "Server")?
Renaming the command block in an anvil sadly does not work.

Comment: The wiki says that renaming in an anvil should work. Can you list the exact sequence of clicks that you do to rename it, maybe something went wrong there?

Comment: What do you mean with secuence of clicks?

Comment: I mean with what mouse button you click on what in what order.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike in the Java Edition, in Minecraft Pocket Edition renaming it in an anvil will not work. You must change the hover note in the command block editor.

[image]

Once you enter in the command and activate the command block with redstone, it should say `[(Hover Note)](Playername) is cool`.

Comment: Just don’t use this with a /tell command, as the Hover Note’s name will get repeated twice.