# Why do I get [!] instead of a name using /say on a command block in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition, xbox-one

I'm using Xbox One Minecraft, and when I name a command block using an anvil, it appears as [!] when the command is run through the chat. I don't use Internet on my Xbox, because it will force an Xbox update that doesn't even work. I have 1.14, so that might be the problem.

Comment: Could you include more information? Maybe a screenshot or photo might help to clarify the question and show us things that could be the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In MCPE:How do i make a command block not have the typical \[@\] infront of a /say msg](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/321507/in-mcpehow-do-i-make-a-command-block-not-have-the-typical-infront-of-a-say)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put the name into the bar titled "Hover Note" in the command block it should work.